# Difference between ng serve --port 4200 and ng serve --host ip:4200

Tags: angular

How can I serve the Angular application on the same port one in my localhost by ng serve command and one in my IPv4 address allocated by my router by ng serve --host 192.168.12.100 running on the same port i.e 4200 and I cannot make two application run on the same port using ng serve twice it gives error another application is running on the same port and I also know we can change the default port by ng serve --port 4000

Running the same application twice in a different environment

ng serve 
ng serve --host ip

here ip is the IPv4 address allocated to the system

Answer (score 2):

```
ng serve --port 4200 :
```

just change port number but host remain same default host is "localhost"

```
and ng serve --host ip:4200 :
```

it change IP or domain example abc.com

or you can change in `angular-cli.json` or `angular.json`

```
{
  "defaults": {
    "serve": {
      "port": 4444,
      "host": "10.1.2.3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know how to change the ip but the thing I am trying to understand the ng serve --port 4200 and ng serve --host ip:4200 run on the same port without causing any error.

Comment: This answer need to be updated. I think "defaults" property is no longer supported in angular.json. I'm using **angular-cli version 8.3.22**. When I read the json schema in `./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json` I don't see `defaults` property in there. My reading of schema is: A `port` property can be added under "serve"(Find "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server") -> "options" property or in one of the config objects under "configurations" if you want to use different port based on the run-config.